# C: save value from type of pointer to struct into struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have define a type struct like that:

```
typedef struct _liste {
    int val;
    struct _liste *suiv;
} Liste;
```

But when I want to save valuer into type but it not work 
my code:

```
Liste A;
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        scanf("%d",&A.val);
        *A = A.suiv
    }
```

but variable A is not saved. 
How to fix? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to create a single-linked list?

Comment: You'll want to set the next pointer to NULL and then take it from there. `*A = A.suiv` is nonsense, you can't do programming by trial & error - you have to actually understand what every single line of code you write does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
typedef struct _liste {
    int val;
    struct _liste *suiv;
} Liste;

Liste A;
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        scanf("%d",&A.val);
        *A = A.suiv
    }
```

there are 2 problems

- `*A = A.suiv` is invalid and you wanted `A = *(A.suiv)` to respect the types (out of any behavior)
- `A.suiv` is not initialized, you miss an allocation for each new cell

A valid code can be :

```
Liste * head;
Liste ** p = &head;

for (int i = 0; i != 3; i++) {
   *p = malloc(sizeof(Liste));
   scanf("%d",&(*p)->val);
   p = &(*p)->suiv;
}
*p = NULL;
```

---

A full example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _liste {
  int val;
  struct _liste *suiv;
} Liste;

int main()
{
  Liste * head;
  Liste ** p = &head;

  for (int i = 0; i != 3; i++) {
    *p = malloc(sizeof(Liste));
    printf("valeur: ");
    scanf("%d",&(*p)->val); /* better to check scanf return 1 */
    p = &(*p)->suiv;
  }
  *p = NULL;

  /* show result and free ressources */
  printf("la liste est :");
  while (head != NULL) {
    printf(" %d", head->val);
    Liste * l = head;
    head = head->suiv;
    free(l);
  }
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra l.c
/tmp % ./a.out
valeur: 1
valeur: 2
valeur: 3
la liste est : 1 2 3
```

execution under *valgrind*

```
/tmp % valgrind ./a.out
==32505== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32505== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32505== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32505== Command: ./a.out
==32505== 
valeur: 1
valeur: 2
valeur: 3
la liste est : 1 2 3
==32505== 
==32505== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32505==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32505==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 48 bytes allocated
==32505== 
==32505== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==32505== 
==32505== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==32505== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

---

If you do not want to have the list in the heap :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _liste {
  int val;
  struct _liste *suiv;
} Liste;

#define N 3

int main()
{
  Liste liste[N];

  for (int i = 0; i != N; i++) {
    printf("valeur: ");
    scanf("%d", &liste[i].val); /* better to check scanf return 1 */
    liste[i].suiv = &liste[i + 1];
  }
  liste[N-1].suiv = NULL;

  /* show result (as a list, forget in an array) */
  Liste * p = liste;

  printf("la liste est :");
  while (p != NULL) {
    printf(" %d", p->val);
    p = p->suiv;
  }
  putchar('\n');
}
```

but in that case better to not use a list but just an array of *int* ;-)

Comment: your code not work, the programmer exit with code -1073741819

Comment: @TranQuocGiaCat I added a full program with executions

Comment: thank you very much, but I don't understand why we do double pointer in variable p?

Comment: @TranQuocGiaCat the double pointer allows to write on the field _suiv_ of the previously created Liste or on _head_ the first time. _head_ is a `Liste * ;` so the address of _head_ is a `Liste ** ;` etc. Do you understand ?

Comment: yes, and so far, if I want to use 1 pointer `*` and 1 variable normal so what should I do?

Comment: @TranQuocGiaCat the _variable normal_ can just contains the head, the 2 next cells need to be allocated, and to do that make the code more complicated for nothing. An other way is to have a `Liste v[3];` and do not allocate any cell but in that case why to use a list and support it in a vector ? ;-)